# R Function for Assigning Multiple String Values to One Value

Tags: r, database, dataframe, dplyr

In my data frame (df), there is a column in my data set called "Subcategory". It returns all the values which are indented

Advertising and Marketing

- TV Ads
- Website Ads
- Radio Ads

Employee Benefits

- Retirement
- Team Building
- Medical Insurance

Insurance

- Legal Insurance
- Business Insurance
- Rental Insurance

All together there are 46 subcategories that are supposed to be assigned to 12 main categories. What's the quickest way in R to assign and match these subcategories to a new column called Category with the appropriate matching?

Comment: Create a look up table with columns for main category, subcategory then merge that (with `base::merge` or `dplyr::left_join` to add the info to your main table. It's easier to help you if you provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Answer (score 0):

```
library(dplyr)

df <- df %>%
  mutate(Category = case_when(
    Subcategory %in% c("TV Ads","Website Ads","Radio Ads") ~ "Advertising and Marketing",
    Subcategory %in% c("Retirement","Team Building","Medical Insurance") ~ "Employee Benefits"
  ))
```